# Losing texture after export?

Tags: meshlab

I'm losing my textures after I export as an .obj or .ply.

I'm utilizing meshes that were created with Meshroom (https://alicevision.github.io/), and I have the textures with the 3D file. After I import into Meshlab to crop out the extraneous (background) vertices, I lose the textures after I export. Looking at the .mtl files, everything appears correctly referenced. This seems like a simple problem, so I must be missing a step?

Appreciate any thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with exports from Photoscan/Metascan. The problem was that my filename included spaces. Once I replaced them with underscores, etc. it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Worth trying to use short filenames on export (less than 8 symbols) without non-ASCII symbols and "spaces".